# $\mathcal N=2$ Weyl multiplet and chiral superfields in 4d

Tags: supersymmetry, topological-field-theory

It is more or less known that a given antisymmetric tensor $F$ in two indices can be written in terms of spinorial indices, splitting into self-dual and anti-self-dual parts
$$ F_{\mu\nu} =
F_{\alpha\beta}
(\sigma_\mu)^{\alpha\dot\alpha}(\sigma_\nu)^{\beta\dot\beta}
\varepsilon_{\dot\alpha\dot\beta} +
F_{\dot\alpha\dot\beta}
(\sigma_\mu)^{\alpha\dot\alpha}(\sigma_\nu)^{\beta\dot\beta}
\varepsilon_{\alpha\beta} .$$

My question is the following:
start from [(equations 5.3 and 5.4)](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9307158)
$$ W_{\mu\nu}^{ij} = T_{\mu\nu}^{ij} -
R_{\mu\nu\lambda\rho}\theta^i\sigma_{\lambda\rho}\theta^j + \cdots $$
which is self-dual in Lorentz indices $\mu\nu$ and antisymmetric
in $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ indices $ij$.
Then it is squared to
$$W^2= \varepsilon_{ij}\varepsilon_{kl} W_{\mu\nu}^{ij}W_{\mu\nu}^{kl}.$$
How do I see (possibly using the first equation above) that this is the same as a tensor [(formula 4.1 and below)](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9912123)
$W_{\alpha\beta}$ with self-dual $T$ as top component, where $\alpha$, $\beta$ denote symmetric spinor indices and
$$W^2=W_{\alpha\beta}W_{\alpha'\beta'}
\varepsilon^{\alpha\alpha'}\varepsilon^{\beta\beta'} ?$$